# Block Flash player installation dialog in IE9

Tags: security, registry, internet-explorer-9, flash

I'm using IE9 (must use it and no other browsers) and it is forbidden to install Adobe Flash Player (it is given). Is there a way to disable those security warnings about the web site is asking to install the flash player? I read [this](http://tnerd.com/2010/02/18/how-to-block-flash-on-chrome-firefox-opera-internet-explorer-8/comment-page-1/) article but it handles blocking flash only after installation which doesn't fit to my needs.

10x,
Guy

***Edit:***

I'm using a Web Browser Control on top of IE9. My application should run independently on any machine (the IE9 installed in). I need some solution that I can change some registry key for instance in order to prevent it from popping up.

Comment: You could may play with your registery and fake the system that the GUID of Adobe Flash is known.

Comment: @rekire - Can you please elaborate more on your suggestion?

Comment: In the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID path are many GUIDs registed I think it should be possible to add a suitable key to fake that the plugin is installed.